# How to force waiting for setUp to end in dart?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, dart, stream, async-await

I have an async test which I setup by adding some items to a stream in the `setUp` method. The setup itself is sync and doesn't require any special treatment. Unfortunately the test fires before my `setUp` has finished! How do I achieve that "waiting mechanism" when I can't use `await` because as mentioned, there is no `async` code in `setUp`? I tried adding `async` but there is nothing to wait for...

An example:
I have a `_bloc` object which increments & emits a score (`int`) whenever a click event is added to its clicks sink.

```
  group("after 10 clicks", () {
    setUp(() {
      List.generate(10, (i) => i).forEach((_) {
        _bloc.clicks.add(null);
      });
    });

    test("score is 10", () async {
      var _score = await _bloc.score.first;

      expect(_score, equals(10));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test don't run before `setUp` has complete. But it DOES run before all the desired events occur, and that is beacuse of the async nature of the `BLoC` object. The `clicks` are all performed but the `score` stream didn't emit all of the corresponding events yet, because it's still processing the input click events.

Anyway, as for the question, an `async` callback in the `setUp` function completes before the test runs.

Answer (score 1):

Make `setUp` async and return a `Future` that completes when `setUp` is done.

The test framework waits for this `Future` to complete before it runs the test.

Comment: I'm apparently doing something wrong, as this doesn't help. Can you give a code sample please? Thank you

Comment: You already have the code. Please edit your question and add it there. The only thing that I can imagine is that the returned Future is not completing when you think it is.

Comment: I think maybe you're right. But just to make sure: I have to `return`? And the `Future` should has `await` before it? And last: should the inner computation should be `async`? I guess it depends if I `await` or not...?

Comment: No `await` required after `return`: `return someFuture;`

Comment: I removed the acceptance because I couldn't reproduce the situation in a different test file which I created for this purpose. I noticed that the `setUp` function always completes before the test is run. Apparently an `async` function always returns a `Future`? The problem in my test was other. Anyhow it seems that no return is needed in `setUp`. Please provide a counterexample if you can.